#  Boolean inside of Select()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a person table filled with Person information. I would like to get a list of the personer inside the table and check if they have renewed thier password in last 24 hours, and then return a person name and a boolean property whether they have updated the password or not.

This is my Person table:

Person table:

```
varchar(30) Name,
DateTime LastRenewedPassword.
```

Code:

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public boolean HasRenewedPassword { get; set; }
}

public List<Person> GetPersons()
{
    using(var context = Entities())
    {
        var persons = from p in contex.Persons
                      select new Person
                      {
                          Name = p.Name,
                          HasRenewedPassword = // Has the personer renewed the password   for the last 24 hours?
                      }
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I, inside of select new {...} return if the personer have renewed the password or not?

All help is appriciated!
And I´m open for any other suggestions for solution to this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
// As noted in comments, there are serious problems with this approach
// unless you store everything in UTC (or local time with offset).
DateTime renewalCutoff = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24);

using(var context = Entities())
{
    var persons = from p in context.Persons
                  select new Person
                  {
                      Name = p.Name,
                      HasRenewedPassword = p.LastRenewedPassword > renewalCutoff
                  };
}
```

(By evaluating `DateTime.Now` *once* and at the client side, it's likely to be easier to debug what's going on at any time - you can log that query parameter, for example.)

Note that as you're only doing a projection, you can simplify your code a bit:

```
var persons = context.Persons.Select(p => new Person {
                  Name = p.Name,
                  HasRenewedPassword = p.LastRenewedPassword > renewalCutoff
              });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I knew I was close, but didn´t know how close ;)

Comment: Pedantic: Won't both this and Marc's answer fail slightly during DST changes (if you don't use UtcNow)? I don't think DateTime adjusts for that.  That is, it *technically* violates Erik's requirement (though it probably does what he wants).

Comment: @Brian: If the value stored isn't in UTC, then I'm not sure this can be fixed. Basically one shouldn't store local times, at least without  offsets :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think you could fix it via careful use of [`IsDaylightSavingsTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime.aspx), but it would make the code more complicated.  There's also some XP-specific ugliness if you want to use it on anything but dates within close range of `DateTime.Now`, since it is coded to always use the current adjustment rule rather than the adjustment rule specific to that date.  There are other gotchas (e.g., make sure to use the correct current culture).

Comment: @Brian: No, you fundamentally *couldn't* fix it. Around a "fall back" DST transition, an hour (typically) of local time occurs twice. If the password renewal occurs within that period, you can't tell whether it was (say) 23 hours and 40 minutes ago or 24 hours and 40 minutes ago... (and then there are other problems besides ambiguity... but that's enough!)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Gah, you mention that issue in a big chunk of your Noda Time articles.  I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @Brian: Glad someone's reading :) Have edited the post to emphasize the importance of UTC.

Comment: Superpedantic:) No answer to this question will work because it's a LINQ to Entities query, `Person` is an entity in the model and you cannot project into entities in LTE.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I'm *guessing* something like:

```
var cutoff = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
...
 select new Person
  {
      Name = p.Name,
      HasRenewedPassword = p.PasswordChanged >= cutoff
  }
```

Comment: @George I think I lost that fight a ***long*** time ago ;p

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select new Person
{
         Name = p.Name,
         HasRenewedPassword = (DateTime.Now - p.LastRenewedPassword).TotalHours <= 24
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TimeSpan:

```
HasRenewedPassword = (DateTime.Now - p.LastRenewedPassword).TotalHours <= 24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var renewalTime = DateTime.Now.Substract(new TimeSpan(24,0,0));

// insert in the select code
HasRenewedPassword = p.LastRenewedPassword > renewalTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this value by adding a simple condition to your select that checks how many hours/days have elapsed since the password was renewed. Use a timespan to validate the elapsed time, like this:

```
var persons = from p in contex.Persons 
              select new Person 
              { 
                  Name = p.Name, 
                  HasRenewedPassword = (DateTime.Now - p.LastRenewedPassword).TotalDays > 1;
              }
```